# How to add table in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a project that I made in Asp.net with Entity Framework.

Now I want to add one or more tables in the database and one or more stored procedures.
But entities not shows the new table.

How to show this?

Comment: Sorry but its very hard to understand your question.  Are you using a database first approach in EF and generating the edmx from the database?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Open edmx file, right click anywhere in the modal and select "Update Model from Database" and follow the instructions and choose the desired tables and SPs.

[image]

Sometimes even after following these steps, your model will not get updated, close Visual Studio and restart it again. This has happened many times for me.

Comment: Make sure you hit Save once you've Updated the Model from Database. ;)

Comment: When I do this, it creates an a table in the diagram, but not the class which I need to reference the table from code.

Comment: When i try this, it gives me a lot of warnings with code 6002(i.e. says some of my tables, which any of them is not the table i want to add, do not have primary key defined) and does not add my specific table(that i select from Update Wizard). Do you have any idea how to solve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sharique's answer is the good one. But I noticed a thing: when the Mapping Details window is active(near Error List, Output) and if you are trying to add a new Entity (right click the design surface, Add -> Entity), the popup dialog, "Add Entity" it won't show.