# Adding new model/table to existing .NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

So I made a new model called notifications and added

```
public virtual DBSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
```

to my context file. So I have:

```
public class myContext : IdentityDbContext
{
  // ... my existing tables and models
   public virtual DBSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
```

I noticed that theres an `onConfiguring()` in this file thats not being used and an `OnModelCreating()` which seems to be used to map Identity stuff to my db Tables like IdentityUser.

Besides adding that new line in my context class, what else would I have to do to be able to use my new table? I noticed that some of the existing tables aren't mentioned in `OnModelCreating()` so I'm not sure how they were added. Would I have to physically add a new table in my db or does entity handle this some how.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If you are, then just use the update model feature from the EDMX. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466347/how-to-add-table-in-entity-framework

Comment: Depends on two of things you didn't mention (yet): 1) how did you create/maintain the database and the EF class model until now? 2) Is `Notification` related to any other existing entity class? Besides that its always good to use the applicable EF version tag.

Comment: I'm taking over this project so I'm not quite sure how it was maintained before. I am using the Entitty Framework. Notification is related to one other table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run tow below commands in **Package Manager Console**

1. `Enable-Migrations`: Enables the migration in your project by
   creating a Configuration class (need to be run only one time per project).
2. `Add-Migration AddNotifications`: Creates a new migration class as per specified name with the `Up()` and `Down()` methods.
3. `Update-Database`: Executes the last migration file created by the `Add-Migration` command and applies changes to the database schema.

You can read more about migrations [Entity Framework Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Does this create the table within the database? What if the table already exists?

Comment: Yes, If exist it will only update it with new changes if there is any changes in the model

Comment: And if any change is made on the database side, will the compiler catch this when compiling the web application? Won't it want another migration?

Comment: No, You are using Code First and your changes should be add in model first then migrated to the database, Also any changes not migrated will throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Consequently, I am not a fan of allowing the web application to dictate the creation and management of the data model >:[

Comment: Welcome, You can use Database first instead of Code First, In database first you can always update model from the database.

Comment: Agreed. What I was trying to get at is that the web application becomes littered with migrations within the project. Seems unnecessary. Do you perform any type if migration handling or do you have another method that removes them altogether?

Comment: The Package manager console is what I get from cmd-shift-p in visual studio code right?

Comment: I didn't use it in visual studio code before but for Visual Studio `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console` or `Alt T N O`

Comment: I can't seem to find it on visual studio code. I'm wondering if its a Visual Studio only feature? Is it equivalent to running those `dotnet ef `commands in the terminal?

Comment: The Package Manager Console provides a PowerShell interface within Visual Studio on Windows to interact with NuGet through the specific commands.<br/>
Its built into Visual Studio on Windows version 2012 and later. (It is not included with Visual Studio for Mac or Visual Studio Code.)

Comment: Ah well that explains it. I'm using Visual Studio Code on a Mac

Comment: @user6728767 You can run these commands throw `dotnet ef migrations add Initial` and 
`dotnet ef database update`