# Auto create tables (Code first) using Entity Framework WITH MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm writing this post because I need help with my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I'm using Entity Framework with Identity

This is the `dbcontext` class. The Settings `DbSet` is only for testing. Here Identity must create automatically all the tables such as `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`, etc as it does with a Sql Server, that is called

**Code First** if I am not wrong.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<SettingsDataModel> Settings { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Fluent API
            modelBuilder.Entity<SettingsDataModel>().HasIndex(a => a.Name);
        }
    }
```

So, there I create the database class, the ASP.NET app inits the database here:

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseMySQL(IoCContainer.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In the **Startup** class. Note I'm using MySql because I will host the application in an App Engine on Google Cloud Platform, that is why the code has **.UseMySQL**.
And in the `HomeController` is where I execute **EnsureCreated** method.

```
    protected ApplicationDbContext mContext;

    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> mUserManager;

    protected SignInManager<ApplicationUser> mSignInManager;

    public HomeController(
        ApplicationDbContext context,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mUserManager = userManager;
        mSignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        mContext.Database.EnsureCreated(); //<-- It returns false

        if (!mContext.Settings.Any()) //<-- Here it throws an exception saying that the database no exists
        {
            mContext.Settings.Add(new SettingsDataModel
            {
                Name = "BackgroundColor",
                Value = "Red"
            });

            mContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I hope I explained correctly and I provided all needed classes to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you run database update command?

Comment: @WaelAbbas What command are you talking about?

Comment: `Update-Database` to apply pending migrations to the database

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49699864/3134112) for apply pending migrations to the database.

Comment: Yes, I used it. I migrated the database and I updated it. Identity tables was created, the problem now is that when I want to create new DbContexts with DbSets, it never gets created. I use mContext.Database.EnsureCreated(); but I doesn't create new tables

Comment: your new table is `Settings` ?

Comment: No, my new table is People. Settings were created when I used migrations

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ApplicationDbContext` class make sure you add all needed class as public property like `Settings` Table.

```
public DbSet<PeopleDataModel> People { get; set; }
```

After that, you need to run `Add-Migration AddPeople` command that will create a new migration class with new changes, then run `Update-Database` command to apply pending migrations to the database.