# Bind Data Grid View from two tables using Entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms Application and am using C#, entity framework. i have two tables in database battalion and brigtype . REALATION BETWEEN THEM USING ID .

i am trying to show those two tables in data grid view but one of them only appears. Here is the code I tried :       '''

```
 private void PopulateDataGridView()
    {
        
        using (Data.battdbEntities db = new Data.battdbEntities())
        {
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv.DataSource = db.battalions.ToList();
        }
     }
```

'''

Comment: You need to use JOIN to select data from two tables using entity framework. You can learn about JOIN in entity framework at https://entityframework.net/joining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are only binding `battalions` to `DataSource`. In order to have `brigtype` data on the relation ID as you mentioned you need to join them on ID column:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from s in db.battalions
                            join c in db.brigtypes on s.ID equals c.ID  
                            //where condtion if any                                             
                            select new
                            {
                                //Column list here
                            }).ToList();
```

**OR** [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-operators)

```
dataGridView1.DataSource =     db.battalions.Join(
                               db.brigtypes,
                               battalion => battalion.ID,
                               brigtype => brigtype.ID,
                               (battalion, brigtype) => new
                                {
                                   //Your columns here
                                }).ToList();
```

If your DBContext `battdbEntities` has not added the `brigtypes` then you have to add that table also to context some thing like below -

[How to add table in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466347/how-to-add-table-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to make View and bind the data in gridview.

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/creating-views/create-view-with-join.php

Try this.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Please check the target page is available. without check we don't answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the target page is available today. It may not be available in the future. Read my comment again. A link to another site alone is NOT an acceptable answer here. Follow the links I gave you and read them.